# How to perform scheduled data transfers with AdlCopy?

Tags: azure-data-lake

I'm working on backup and recovery for Data Lake Store. In a nutshell, we need to back up one Data Lake Store to another. I've chosen AdlCopy for that purpose (if you want to know why, check out my previous post: [Backup of Data Lake Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49628322/backup-of-data-lake-store)).
According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-best-practices#resiliency-considerations, AdlCopy supports orchestration through either Azure Automation or Windows Task Scheduler. I'm more keen on using Azure Automation however. Can someone help clarify how I'm supposed to use Azure Automation to run AdlCopy on a schedule? Do I need a VM? AdlCopy only supports Windows 10 and I can't figure out how Azure Automation will help me to achieve a serverless approach (without Data Factory if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to have scheduled copies, it will be best to do it using Azure Data Factory (ADF). AdlCopy works great for quick one-off transfers of data. But for scheduled ones which need full monitoring support, built-in retries etc, ADF will be best. If there are reasons you cannot use ADF, please do let us know.

Thanks,
Sachin Sheth,
Program Manager, Azure Data Lake.